# How do I reduce the summation of a binary variable Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I am working with an optimization problem where I have a variable with 3 indices

Binary Variable: Viup <- i is for no. of tasks, u is the machine, and p is the time

Integer Variable: Xi <- the cost of each task i

I am trying to impose a constraint such that the cost to perform the task should not be more than a fixed quantity (here Budget )that the cost of each task should be calculated only once even though the task is performed by multiple machines many times.

I want to sum the values in Viup such that for each value of i the summation should not be more than 1 or could be 0, so that I can form a an equation something like

Sum of Viup * Xi <= Budget

Learning to formulate ILP equations please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need to know if any of `Viup` is 1 for fixed `u,p` across all `i`.

If you are performing a minimization, one way to do this would be to introduce a binary indicator variable `d_i` and a new constraint

```
sum_i(V_iup)-B*d_i<=0
```

where `B` is a constant and an upper bound for `sum_i(V_iup)`. Now, if `d_i=1`, then `sum_i(V_iup)>=0` otherwise, if `d_i=0` then `sum_i(V_iup)=0`.

You can now rewrite you budget summation as:

```
d_i*X_i<=Budget
```